# Common interface between objects with different fields

Tags: c#, casting, polymorphism

I'm trying to think of the best solution to create a common interface between two objects with different fields.

```
Interface Base {

  void dosomething();
}

Class A : Base {
  string x;
  string y;
  void dosomething();
}

Class B : Base {
  string a;
  string b;
  string c;
  void dosomething();
}
```

The problem is when I create a Base object I would like to still access the fields. The solution I thought of was to use the "as" command to type cast. Is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: It's unclear what you're really trying to achieve here. We don't know what code is creating the objects, or what code is using the objects. It's an XY problem at the moment...

Comment: I basically have another function that takes in a Base Object. There's several derived class of Base. If Base is of type B I'd like to access it's fields a,b,c. The only other solution I thought of was creating a dictionary to store fields but that didn't seem clean.

Comment: Well this sounds like a design issue as much as anything else - it's fairly ugly for one method that takes a Base method to need to know about the concrete subclasses.

Comment: Yeah but I couldn't really think of anything better

Comment: And while we only have a description of your proposed solution to the problem, rather than a description of the actual problem, we can't help you find anything better. That's why it's an XY problem...

Answer (score -1):

You can do that,

Or you can have an intermediate class implementing Base with all five properties x, y, a, b and c defined virtual and returning null (say Base2) and derive your classes from Base2 and only override x and y for A and a, b and c for B

Comment: Thanks. That was what I was thinking also. Which do you think is cleaner? I have like 5 implementations of Base so that would be around 20 fields.

Comment: If the properties of these objects are different then probably they have different responsibilities and have a base class for all of them is not an elegant design, and if you have only the abstraction that a class "does something" then you should stick to that abstraction. Why you need to Access the derived class' properties at the same place is another question.